# "For" loop without "do"; "if" statement without "then"

Tags: algorithms, algorithmicx, algorithmic

How can I get rid of the **do** in a **for** loop and the **then** in an **if** statement when typesetting algorithms using the `algorithm` and `algorithmicx` packages?

Comment: I am confused. Are you talking about some structures for writing algorithms implemented by some package? if so, what package are you using? Or are you referring to cycles and conditionals in (La)TeX? Please add to your question a minimal and complete version of code showing the involved structures and packages used.

Comment: The former, I'm using algorithm and algorithmic.

Comment: Please edit the question- after I read the answers, your question sort-of made sense, but still not very much.

Comment: @cmhughes I think this question makes sense now (in fact, it just helped me!). Perhaps a few words should be added to the question to indicate that it is about the `algorithmicx` package.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can redefine `\algorithmicthen` and `\algorithmicdo`:

```
\renewcommand\algorithmicthen{}
\renewcommand\algorithmicdo{}
```

Adding the previous lines in the preamble (respectively, before a particular algorithmic environment enclosing the construct inside a group) will remove the "then" and "do" from all the `algorithmic` environments (for the particular environment, respectively). If the change has to be applied only to some structures of a particular algorithm while others still will have the "then" and "do", then you can define commands to "switch on/off" the expressions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\newcommand\NoDo{\renewcommand\algorithmicdo{}}
\newcommand\ReDo{\renewcommand\algorithmicdo{\textbf{do}}}
\newcommand\NoThen{\renewcommand\algorithmicthen{}}
\newcommand\ReThen{\renewcommand\algorithmicthen{\textbf{then}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Calculate $y = x^n$}
\label{alg1}
\begin{algorithmic}
\STATE $y \leftarrow 1$
\NoThen
\IF{$n < 0$}
\STATE $X \leftarrow 1 / x$
\ENDIF
\ReThen
\IF{$n > 0$}
\STATE $X \leftarrow 1$
\ENDIF
\NoDo
\FOR{$N \neq 0$}
\STATE $X \leftarrow X \times X$
\ENDFOR
\ReDo
\WHILE{$N \neq 0$}
\STATE $X \leftarrow X \times X$
\ENDWHILE
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Although this may be up to user preference, the [`algorithmicx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) provides a similar interface to that of [`algorithmic`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmic) but with some more (or easy) customization.

Here is an implementation of @Gonzalo's answer that defines `\NoThenIf` ... `\EndIf` and `\NoDoFor` ... `\EndFor` pairs using "the ONE defining macro `\algdef`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\begin{document}

\algdef{SE}[FOR]{NoDoFor}{EndFor}[1]{\algorithmicfor\ #1}{\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicfor}%
\algdef{SE}[IF]{NoThenIf}{EndIf}[1]{\algorithmicif\ #1}{\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicif}%
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Calculate $y = x^n$}\label{alg1}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State $y \leftarrow 1$
    \NoThenIf{$n < 0$}
      \State $X \leftarrow 1 / x$
    \EndIf
    \If{$n > 0$}
      \State $X \leftarrow 1$
    \EndIf
    \NoDoFor{$N \neq 0$}
      \State $X \leftarrow X \times X$
    \EndFor
    \While{$N \neq 0$}
      \State $X \leftarrow X \times X$
    \EndWhile
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

The flags `SE` in both definitions refer to "`S`tarting command with text" and "Continuing command, with default `E`nding text". See the [`algorithmicx` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/algorithmicx.pdf) for more information on these command definitions (section **4.7 The ONE deﬁning macro**, p 20 onward).