# “While” loop without “do”; “if” statement without “then”

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e

I have a similar question as this [“For” loop without “do”; “if” statement without “then”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52349/89388):

> How can I get rid of the do in a for loop and the then in an if
>   statement when typesetting algorithms using the algorithm and
>   algorithmicx packages?

but I want the same thing for **algorithm2e** package.

A minimal compilable example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}
\SetKwRepeat{Do}{do}{while}
\SetKw{KwGoTo}{go to}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\DontPrintSemicolon
\KwIn{$A,B$}
\KwOut{$C$}
\While{$B > 0$}
{
     $C = C+1$;
     $B = B-1$;
    \uIf{$C > A$}
       {
           \textbf{break}\;
       }
}
\caption{ABC}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A minimal compilable example should come with the question, so we have something to start with. Look at `\SetKwFor` and `\SetKwIF`.

Comment: Please check it now.

Comment: Herbert already answered.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}
\SetKwIF{If}{ElseIf}{Else}{if}{}{else if}{else}{end if}%
\SetKwFor{While}{while}{}{end while}%
\SetKwRepeat{Do}{do}{while}
\SetKw{KwGoTo}{go to}
\begin{document}
...
```

[image]