# How to remove "then" after if statement in algorithm2e

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e

I am trying to write a pseudocode and would like to remove the `then` statements showing up after `if` or `else if` statements.

```
\documentclass[ijoc,nonblindrev]{informs3}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,lined, noend]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
  \begin{algorithm}
\DontPrintSemicolon
            \uIf{A}{
                do A\\
             }\uElseIf{B}{
                do B\\
            }\Else{
                skip\\
            }
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A similar question has been asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52349/for-loop-without-do-if-statement-without-then) before, but it did not help me in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redefine how the `if`-related keywords are set:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,lined,noend]{algorithm2e}

% Original definition
% \SetKwIF{If}{ElseIf}{Else}{if}{then}{else if}{else}{end if}%
\SetKwIF{If}{ElseIf}{Else}{if}{}{else if}{else}{end if}%

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \uIf{A}{
    do A\;
  }\uElseIf{B}{
    do B\;
  }\Else{
    skip\;
  }
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```